# Issue with extending the core block

Tags: magento-2.1.2

I am trying to extend the core block here.

This is my block :

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Review\Block\Product;

/**
 * Product Review Tab
 *
 * @author     Custom Team
 */
class ListView extends \Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView {

    /**
     *
     * @var \Vendor\Review\Model\LikedislikeFactory
     */
    protected $likedislikeFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Vendor\Review\Model\LikedislikeFactory $likedislikeFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Vendor\Review\Model\LikedislikeFactory $likedislikeFactory
    ) {
        $this->likedislikeFactory = $likedislikeFactory;
    }

    public function getReviewLikesData($id = '') {
        if (!empty($id)) {
            $countDisLike = $this->likedislikeFactory->create()->getCollection();
            $countDisLike->addFieldToFilter('review_id', $id);
            $countDisLike->addFieldToFilter('like_status', 1);
            if (count($countDisLike) > 0) {
                return count($countDisLike);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public function getReviewDisLikesData($id = '') {
        if (!empty($id)) {

            $countDisLike = $this->likedislikeFactory->create()->getCollection();
            $countDisLike->addFieldToFilter('review_id', $id);
            $countDisLike->addFieldToFilter('like_status', 0);

            if (count($countDisLike) > 0) {
                return count($countDisLike);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

The problem is that I have to inject all the dependencies used in parent class.

If I am extending some class, I should have all its dependencies and I should be able to add other dependencies in my block. What if core magento changes its dependencies in future, in that case my module will stop working due to mismatch of dependencies.

Let me know the possible solution or an alternative way to achieve this.

Thanks and apology for using the **dependencies** word frequently !

Comment: You can try using plugin method, you can override public method using plugin.

Comment: I don't want to override any method actually. I just want existing functionality as well as to add few functions of my own.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is not to overwrite the constructor and to get objects via ObjectManager.

For example:

```
/**
 * @var \RB\Review\Model\Likedislike
 */
public $likedislike;

public function getLikedislike()
{
    if (!$this->likedislike) {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $this->likedislike = $objectManager->create('RB\Review\Model\Likedislike');
    }

    return $this->likedislike;
}

public function getReviewLikesData($id = '') {
    if (!empty($id)) {
        $countDisLike = $this->getLikedislike()->getCollection();
        $countDisLike->addFieldToFilter('review_id', $id);
        $countDisLike->addFieldToFilter('like_status', 1);
        if (count($countDisLike) > 0) {
            return count($countDisLike);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative way but I am already aware of it. What I personally want is to use constructor here and as such object manager is not recommended to use like this.